# Store setInterval in array

Tags: javascript

I got a bit confused about a code snippet that I took from the react.js docs: 
http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

But I converted it to a general js case:

```
var SomeFunc = function(){
    this.intervals = []; 
    this.setInterval = function(){
        this.intervals.push(setInterval.apply(null, arguments));
    }; 
    var self = this; 
    this.cleanup = setTimeout(function(){ 
        self.intervals.map(clearInterval);
    }, 3000); 
}

var someFunc = new someFunc(); 
someFunc.setInterval(this.tick, 1000); 
someFunc.cleanup();
```

I'm confused by the following line:

```
this.intervals.push(setInterval.apply(null, arguments));
```

When I console.log the the argument of `push`, it returns `1`.
Can someone explain what actually gets stored in this array?
The cleanup works, so why does the array show the array index number (+1?) instead of what is actually stored in the array?

React.js jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xsjfq5ex/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) returns the interval ID, so that is what gets stored in your array:

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function. Returns an intervalID.
>
> intervalID is a unique interval ID you can pass to `clearInterval()`.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Accept in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a property called `setInterval` on the object whose constructor is `SomeFunc`. The property is a function that simply delegates the task of creating an interval to the global `setInterval`, but also keeps track of the ones it creates.

Using `setInterval.apply(null, arguments)`, you are essentially calling the global `setInterval`, and passing the arguments down to that (which would be the function to execute and the interval in milliseconds). The `null` indicates what `this` will reference inside the body of the function.

`setInterval()` will create the interval and return the ID assigned to that interval; this ID is what you are storing in the array. When you call `cleanup`, you are mapping the array via `clearInterval`, which accepts the ID of the interval to clear (and in this case, is passed in via `map`'s callback.

So in simple terms, you're creating an intermediate layer to store the intervals as if they're "assigned" to the object you created. This makes them easier to clear when you're finished.

Comment: Why use `apply()` instead of simply calling the regular `setTimeout(cb,1000)`?

Comment: @Pier It seems to be a choice the original author of the code made. That way, he doesn't have to specify the callback and interval time as parameters to the `this.setInterval` function.